expo-asset 51, assets specified in plugins not loading
I am struggling to get to grips with expo-asset could someone offer some advice?
I am trying to use expo-asset to preload my image asset ahead of it being required on-screen, this is to hopefully eliminate the blink from black screen to image that is currently happening while the image is loading. (I am using the image as a background so it is extremely noticeable.
This is the current image setup (using expo-image):
<Image source={require("../../assets/images/authBackground.jpg")} contentFit='cover' className='absolute w-full h-full -z-20'/>

Reading: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/
Any advice would be great, or if theres another direction I should be going thats welcome too
I have tried setting the following in app.json:
"plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      [
        "expo-asset",
        {
          "assets:": ["./assets/images/authBackground.jpg"]
        }
      ]
    ],

& then using this in the image, but I get a black screen the image never loads:
<Image source="authBackground" contentFit='cover' className='absolute w-full h-full -z-20'/>


did you ever figure it out?
